# How do I disable links in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Since a few months ago, Notepad++ automatically makes clickable links whenever I type a URL. This behaviour makes it much more difficult to edit HTML documents because instead of clicking in the middle of a text URL to change it, it now opens the link in the web browser instead.

How can I permanently disable this feature?

Comment: Amazing how the NPP team persists in enalbing this idiotic option by default. Not a single developer has ever needed to click a link in NPP.

Comment: Agreed! The same goes for the Workspace feature (disable by unchecking under Default Directory in Settings > Preferences). At first you couldn't disable it at all, so I didn't upgrade for a couple years. Now you can disable so I can use the latest version, which finally has a dark theme.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

This has moved to the **Settings > Preferences > Cloud & Link**

[image]

---

### For users of the older versions:

You have to uncheck this option:

Settings » Preferences » MISC » Clickable Link Settings

[image: Clickable Link Settings]

Once you've changed the setting, you will need to reopen the file in Notepad++ (or restart the application) for it to take effect.

Comment: @ReverseEMF I actually used the links frequently while writing HTML files for my website. Making sure they're going where I think they're going and also I'd sometimes want to read stuff from the site I was referencing while writing content for the page.

Comment: @nixda, I often find myself toggling this, (and I keep forgetting where in the unintuitive menu it is), any easy way to do this, like assign a key ?

Comment: **Note:** this has moved to the **Cloud & Link** page

Answer (score 6):

As a Windows 10 user, I found that I needed to run Notepad++ as an administrator in order for this setting to "take". This is probably true for other versions of Windows.

I discovered this after several attempts to uncheck the *Clickable Link Settings* checkbox.  After restarting Notepad++ several times and finding the checkbox *still checked*, I found this solution from searching Google.

Comment: Can confirm that this worked in my case. Had to run Notepad++ in admin mode in order to be able to "deactivate" links.

Comment: Did you install Notepad++ with the option `Do not use %APPDATA%`? This would be the only explanation for me.

Comment: This problem doesn't occur in my case. I'm running as a normal user and the setting change had definitely "taken" after a single restart.